# ¿Dónde puedo descargar Groovy and Grails Tool Suite?

Tags: grails, groovy

He consultado el [enlace](https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all), sin embargo aparece el error de página no encontrada, también he buscado en la página de spring pero parece ser que ya no ofrecen un enlace para la descarga.

Comment: Ya no se está desarrollando, ni actualizando GGTL. ¿Qué necesitas especificamente? Ya que puedes utilizar algún IDE que te acomode y sumarle algunos plugins.

Comment: Qué IDE puedo usar? He intentado con NetBeans 8.2 pero al parecer no soporta Grails 3.x. Y por lo que veo está IntelliJ Ultimate pero es de pago.

Comment: Revisa este link. Hay varios ejemplos, con distintos IDEs [Grails 3 IDE Setup](http://grails.asia/grails-3-tutorial-setup-your-windows-development-environment/)